# Adding in an array after message.content discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I'm trying to make my discord bot filter specific words out which I have set in my Array:

```js
let Blacklist = ['bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3']
```

But the problem is that I don't really know how to have this in the Message.content, I've looked it up all over the internet but couldn't find it.
The code I have right now:

```js
 else if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(Blacklist))
  message.delete() && message.author.send("Keep the use of Profanity out of our server!");
```

How would I go by entering the array into the message's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the blacklist and check for each individual word like so:

```
let Blacklist=["bad","dumb"]
for(let word of Blacklist){
  if(message.content.includes(word)){
    message.delete()
    message.author.send("warning")
    break;
    }
}
```

I would break out of the loop if there was a bad word in the text so that the user isn't warned multiple times

Answer (score 1):

We could very simply use a `forEach()` function in order to scroll through every element in the array, and check if the message's content includes that element.

This could be done by typing:

```
const blacklist = ['bad word 1', 'bad word 2', 'bad word 3']
    blacklist.forEach(word => {
        // 'word' represents an element inside of the array. 
        // Everytime the client is finished walking through an element, the value of 'word' changes to the next one!
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) message.delete() && message.author.send("Keep the use of Profanity out of our server!")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if message content has atleast one blacklist word

```
const blacklist = ['bad word 1', 'bad word 2', 'bad word 3']
const containsProfanity =  blacklist.some(word => message.content.includes(word))
if(containsProfanity){
  message.delete() && message.author.send("Keep the use of Profanity out of our server!")
}
```